# Hallar Perimetros de una circunferencia

Tags: matemáticas

Me falta desarrollar el siguiente ejercicio pero no lo comprendo, se como hallar el perímetro a partir del radio o el diámetro, pero no logro entender que es lo que toca hacer en el ejercicio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perímetro de circunferencia

```
    P = 2πr
```

Grande:

```
    d = 0.6m 
    r = 0.3m 
    r = 30cm
    P = 2π30 
    P = 60π
```

Chiquita:

```
    r = 18cm
    P = 2π18
    P = 36π
```

Diferencia(resta)

```
    Diferencia = Pgrande - Pchiquita
    Diferencia = 60π - 36π
    Diferencia = π(60 - 36)
```

> Diferencia = 24π
>
> > *La diferencia en la longitud recorrida en un giro completo es de 24π cm*

Answer (score 1):

Tenes dos circunferencias.
Para una te dan el diámetro y para la otra el radio.

Tenes que considerar las ruedas independientemente una de otra dado que de lo contrario la distancia recorrida seria la misma y la diferencia cero.

Entonces la pregunta es cuanto recorre un giro completo de la rueda de adelante?
Y cuánto recorre un giro completo de la de atrás?
Y cual es la diferencia (la resta) de las dos longitudes.